# Run python script every 5 minutes on the clock

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gauge

I'm busy with an python script on a raspberry pi for a rain gauge. 
The script need to count the tips of the bucket and write the total rain amount every 5 minutes to a csv file. The script does the writing now every 299.9 seconds but I want it to write every exact 5 minutes, for example: 14:00, 14:05, 14:10 and so on.

Is there anyone who could help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you have in code? Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: Were the answers useful?

Answer (score 3):

Use a cronjob, for raspberry pi go with crontab
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Answer (score 2):

You will find lots of helpful functions in the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Bootstrap by getting the most recent time that had minutes as a multiple of 5
time_now = datetime.utcnow()  # Or .now() for local time
prev_minute = time_now.minute - (time_now.minute % 5)
time_rounded = time_now.replace(minute=prev_minute, second=0, microsecond=0)

while True:
    # Wait until next 5 minute time
    time_rounded += timedelta(minutes=5)
    time_to_wait = (time_rounded - datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds()
    time.sleep(time_to_wait)

    # Now do whatever you want
    do_my_thing()
```

Note that when `do_my_thing()` is called it will actually be fractionally after the exact time in `time_to_round`, because obviously computers can't do work in precisely zero time. It's guaranteed not to wake up before that time though. If you want to refer to the "current time" in `do_my_thing()`, pass in the `time_rounded` variable so that you get neat timestamps in your log file.

In the code above I've deliberately recomputed `time_to_wait` each time, rather than just setting it to 5 minutes after the first time. That's so that the slight delay I just mentioned don't gradually snowball after you've been running the script for a long time.